# Can't Save Exclusion Script on Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, exclusion-script

I'm attempting to input the following exclusion script on a triggered send in Marketing Cloud. However, whenever I attempt to do so, the exclusion script will not save. I'll click 'Save' and then 'Publish Changes', but the triggered send does not show the exclusion script attached to it. Is there a step I'm missing? My understanding was that you could just type the exclusion script into that area in a triggered send. Exclusion script is:

ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Smart_Alerts","EMAIL_ADDRESS", EMAILADDR))>0

[image]

Comment: This should work. Is the DE in the same business unit, or is it shared?

Comment: It's in the same BU. Should it be shared?

Comment: No, please can you schedule a call at Eliot.com.au so I can assist further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arranged a call with @chorlesbarkley7 to help troubleshoot this one. I thought I'd share the troubleshooting process and the cause for the benefit of others.

1. Open an email and insert the code `%%[if {exclusionscript} then endif]%%` where `{exclusionscript}` is the exclusion script that you are using. Preview the email and see if it returns an error message.
2. If there is no error, then try using the exclusion script `1==1` in your Triggered Send Definition. If the Exclusion Script is removed when you save the Triggered Send Definition, then this would indicate that this feature has not been properly provisioned and you should open a support case.

Comment: Salesforce successfully enabled Exclusion Scripts on the account, and I confirmed it work. So for one final note, even though you may be able to enter a value for exclusions scripts, if it doesn't save, you will need it enabled via a Salesforce Ticket. Thanks again to Eliot Harper for the solve on this one.